# get page html with MozREPL using Firefox 55.0.3 (64-bit)

Tags: firefox, mozrepl

Is this possible at all? MozREPL is now apparently incompatible with this version of Firefox, but Firefox is very hard to stop updating.

I want to automate a browser again, not a headless one.

Is there any browser I can use at all, where i can just simply read the page HTML and automate form submission?

That's it really, last time I done this, Firefox was good for this.

Thanks

Comment: seems i am unlikely to get an answer, i will try a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on linux, you can downgrade to 54, and hold the update. Firefox will complain about not being able to update, but that's it. 
Other possible solution should be a container with firefox 54 installed, but I did not have the time to try it out. The script(s) should be run inside the docker, I suppose.

Comment: thanks for your reply... i finally achieved my objective in one of two ways (but you can't close questions on this website?)

Anyway i found you could disable the net, and set firefox not to update, but safer really I decided to use:

Firefox 52.3.0esr

Also, TOR is (coincident i think not), based on Firefox 52.3.0

No, it's all singing and dancing now.... thanks for your attention